# Evaluate an expression in an environment created from a struct (Julia equivalent of R 'with')

Tags: julia

Is there a way to evaluate an expression in an environment created from the fields of a struct? In R, this can be done using the function `with`:

```
parameters <- list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)

f <- function(parameters, x) {
   with(parameters, a + b * x + c * x^2)
}

f(parameters, 7)
# [1] 162
```

I'd like to be able to do something similar in Julia. For example:

```
struct Parameters
    a::Float64
    b::Float64
    c::Float64
end

function f(p::Parameters, x)
    with(p, a + b * x + c * x^2)
end

p = Parameters(1, 2, 3)
f(p, 7)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way I know of is using [Parameters.jl](https://github.com/mauro3/Parameters.jl):

```
using Parameters

struct Params
    a::Float64
    b::Float64
    c::Float64
end

function f(p::Params, x)
    @unpack a, b, c = p
    a + b * x + c * x^2
end

p = Params(1, 2, 3)
f(p, 7)
```

However, because of explicit mentioning of the field names in `@unpack a, b, c = p` it's not quite as nice.

**UPDATE**:

Actually, Parameters.jl also allows you to unpack all fields, which seems to be exactly what you want. But it's regarded as somewhat dangerous, because of potential type changes/instabilities. See [here](https://mauro3.github.io/Parameters.jl/stable/manual.html#The-type-specific-(un)pack-macros-(somewhat-dangerous)-1) for more detail. Example:

```
using Parameters

@with_kw struct Params
    a::Float64
    b::Float64
    c::Float64
end

function f(p::Params, x)
    @unpack_Params p
    a + b * x + c * x^2
end

p = Params(1, 2, 3)
f(p, 7)
```